# Woocommerce hook o action para carrito de compra

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

tengo una duda,  para Woocommerce existe algun hook o action que me permita obtener la lista que esta almacenada en el carrito de compras. Muchas Gracias. Muchas gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con este código se puede obtener la lista del carrito de compra

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
        $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
        echo "<b>".$_product->get_title().'</b>  <br> Quantity: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>'; 
        $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
        echo "  Price: ".$price."<br>";
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres usar el id del producto en el carrito para ejecutar otro codigo pues añadir esta funcion , va mirando los productos añadidos en el carrito y dependiendo del id de producto pueden compararlo y realizar otras acciones, ten en cuenta que es para las ordenes con el status de completadas pero se podria hacer para ordenes con otros estados diferentes:

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'your_custom_function_call', 10, 1);

```
function your_custom_function_call( $order_id ) { 
     $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
     foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
         //Por ejemplo el producto con id 5271
         if ( $item['product_id'] === 5271 ) {
             //Aqui pondrias el codigo que se ejecuta cuando el producto es el 5271
         }
         //Por ejemplo el producto con id 5272
         elseif ( $item['product_id'] === 5272 ) {
             //Aqui pondrias el codigo que se ejecuta cuando el producto es el 5272
         }
```